# Reposition the Error Icon of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview on a winform that is databound. The grid does not allow edits it's only to view data inconsistancies from comparison of two separate data sources so the fixes can be corrected in the data's Application of record. As I do the compare I set the `SetColumnError` property of the DataRow if there is an issue. The problem is when the databinding is complete and the grid renders the Error Icon is covering parts of the datagridcell data. I have tried several various methods found here on SO and on the web and nothing has worked to move the icon. Any thoughts?

I already set the following when the grid is built in the code behind

```
Padding newpadding = new Padding(10, 0, 30, 0)
datagridview.RowTemplet.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = newPadding
```

But yet this is the result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. After trying many different things I came across a piece of code [here](http://www.windows-tech.info/3/668a65b028f55e85.php) that solved the problem.

Here is before:

[image]

Here is after:

[image]

the changes can be made in the `CellPainting()` Event at least for me. I was databinding a DataSet into a readonly DataGridView. The DataSet already contained the Errors and ErrorText from an internal operation run against the DataSet.

The key code change is `e.CellBounds.X + 30` this pads an extra 30 to the X axis allowing the image to be pushed to the right.

```
private void dgv_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon);
    if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)
    {
        if (this.dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ErrorText != string.Empty)
        {
            Rectangle errorRect = this.dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ErrorIconBounds;
            errorRect.X += e.CellBounds.X + 30;
            errorRect.Y += e.CellBounds.Y;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(gridErrorIcon, errorRect);
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

internal static Image gridErrorIcon
{
    get { return Properties.Resources.Error; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to manipulate the error icon, neither its position nor anything else.

But maybe this little workaround helps: Instead of changing its position, why not remove it altogether, by clearing the error text. If you copy it to a tooltip you can still access its value and even show it to the user.

Instead of the icon, indicate the error by painting the background or the foregreound of the cell.

By combining the `Validating` and the `Validated` events I got it to work for me, one sets the color, the other clears the error indicator but the color still sticks:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    cell.ToolTipText = cell.ErrorText;
    cell.ErrorText = "";
}

private void DGV_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    cell.Style.BackColor = cell.ErrorText != "" ? Color.Salmon : datagridview.BackColor;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @TaW. I looked at that as an option as soon as I saw the problem with the icon but I was hoping that MS foresaw this as a problem and included a way to manipulate the positioning. If I have to go that route I can but I would rather find a solution to the positioning.