# How do I show errors on a current DataGridViewCheckBoxCell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have an application in which one of my screens makes heavy use of `DataGridViewCheckBoxCells`. In short, I have the table set up in `VirtualMode` with an Undo system involved, validation, and so on. In some cases it doesn't make sense to check a box where another box is not first checked and so on. I let users do it, but I have a checking function that sets the cell's `ErrorText` property and doesn't let them continue.

Blah, blah. I've already verified it's not my code clearing the `ErrorText` or anything like that. The problem is `DataGridViewCheckBoxCells` do not paint the error icon / glyph thingy when it is the current cell. I cannot reason why they were designed this way. Indeed the reference source ([DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.cs)) backs me up:

In DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.cs:

```
protected override Rectangle GetErrorIconBounds(Graphics graphics, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, int rowIndex)
{
    // some checks ...

    Point ptCurrentCell = this.DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress;
    if (ptCurrentCell.X == this.ColumnIndex &&
        ptCurrentCell.Y == rowIndex && this.DataGridView.IsCurrentCellInEditMode)
    {
        // PaintPrivate does not paint the error icon if this is the current cell.
        // So don't set the ErrorIconBounds either.
        return Rectangle.Empty;
    }

    // behavior ...
}
```

and taking a look at `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.PaintPrivate`:

```
private Rectangle PaintPrivate(Graphics g, 
    Rectangle clipBounds,
    Rectangle cellBounds, 
    int rowIndex, 
    DataGridViewElementStates elementState,
    object formattedValue,
    string errorText,
    DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
    DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
    DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts,
    bool computeContentBounds,
    bool computeErrorIconBounds,
    bool paint)
{
    // blah blah

    // here it determines "If I am the current cell DO NOT draw the error icon!"
    Point ptCurrentCell = this.DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress;
    if (ptCurrentCell.X == this.ColumnIndex && 
        ptCurrentCell.Y == rowIndex && this.DataGridView.IsCurrentCellInEditMode)
    {
        drawErrorText = false;
    }

    // sure enough, drawErrorText must be true here for the error icon to be drawn
    if (paint && DataGridViewCell.PaintErrorIcon(paintParts) && drawErrorText && this.DataGridView.ShowCellErrors)
    {
        PaintErrorIcon(g, cellStyle, rowIndex, cellBounds, errorBounds, errorText);
    }
}
```

How can I get around this? I tried to subclass `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` to little avail. There are so many internal functions and constants I can't hit. I tried to hack it in the `Form` that uses this table, and I managed to de-select the current cell if it is a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` after its `DirtyStateChanged` which I am intercepting anyway (for [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932040/triggering-a-checkbox-value-changed-event-in-datagridview-c-net)). But this doesn't work--when a user selects a cell, sure enough, the error icon disappears. I can't intercept and block `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`s from being selected with `SelectionChanged`, because selection is the first step in the process of editing a cell's value.

What can I do?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562966/reposition-the-error-icon-of-a-datagridview/24600915#24600915) describes a workaround: Instead of  the ErrorIcon is uses a Backcolor to indicate an error..

Comment: That could be one way, thanks. Unfortunately, I am already using `BackColor` for a visual aid to understanding the context of the cell, or its meaning. But, perhaps I could mesh these together by "flashing" back and forth between two colors.

Answer (score 0):

The following code draws a "beautiful" error icon in every cell that has an error text. You may have to adapt it to your specific case :

```
static Icon m_errorIcon;

public static Icon ErrorIcon
{
    get
    {
        if (m_errorIcon == null)
        {
            ErrorProvider errorProvider = new ErrorProvider();
            m_errorIcon = errorProvider.Icon;
            errorProvider.Dispose();
        }
        return m_errorIcon;
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if ((e.PaintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon) != 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.ErrorText))
        {
            Icon icon = ErrorIcon;
            int pixelMargin = 2;

            Rectangle cellBounds = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X + pixelMargin, e.CellBounds.Y, e.CellBounds.Width - 2 * pixelMargin, e.CellBounds.Height);
            Rectangle firstIconRectangle = new Rectangle(cellBounds.Left, cellBounds.Top + Math.Max((cellBounds.Height - icon.Width) / 2, 0), Math.Min(icon.Width, cellBounds.Width), Math.Min(icon.Width, cellBounds.Height));

            e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, e.PaintParts & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon);
            e.Graphics.DrawIcon(icon, firstIconRectangle);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    }
}
```